# Bluetooth errors during boot - Debian 9 Stretch 4.16.0-2-amd64

Tags: debian, boot, bluetooth

I'm using Debian 9 Stretch with kernel 4.16.0-2-amd64 on my Dell Latitude E7240.

After installing fresh OS, updating everything and configuring, I've got a strange problem on startup.

First, bluetooth service took 3min to start, so I disabled it.
Then, network manager wait-on, took about 20 sec, so I disabled it too.

Now i have some strange output, from bluetooth. I tried complete uninstalling bluetooth but nothing changed!

I mean i did:
sudo apt-get purge blueman bluez-utils bluez bluetooth
sudo apt-get purge bluetooth

This is still in settings but seems like not working.

```
[ 5.152080] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfc8e tx timeout
[13.280070] Bluetooth: hci0: sending Intel patch command (0xfc8e) failed (-110)
[13.282058] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-19)
[15.296114] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfc11 tx timeout
[15.296114] Bluetooth: hci0: Exiting manufacturer mode failed (-110)
```

So now I don't even have a bluetooth in OS.

The most fun thing, is it will never startup! Until i start spamming some key, i.e: ctrl, alt, even when I'm spamming ctrl+alt+F1.

I never excepted problems like this in any OS, and I'm sad of changing from Debian, because i really enjoy it.

EDIT: I found out, when I entering recovery mode in grub and choosing older kernel, everything booting up smoothly.

EDIT2: I dont want to remove bluetooth completely. I would really appreciate if someone make a mini tutorial how to repair this usse and get back to working bluetooth without startup bug.

```
       529ms dev-sda1.device
       528ms systemd-logind.service
       310ms dev-loop0.device
       279ms dev-loop1.device
       258ms dev-loop2.device
       220ms upower.service
       151ms ModemManager.service
       133ms avahi-daemon.service
       133ms keyboard-setup.service
       131ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       117ms accounts-daemon.service
       115ms udisks2.service
       112ms snap-libreoffice-65.mount
       104ms rtkit-daemon.service
       102ms rsyslog.service
        98ms wpa_supplicant.service
        97ms NetworkManager.service
        96ms apparmor.service
        95ms snap-firefox-103.mount
        91ms systemd-journald.service
        83ms snap-core-4917.mount
        78ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-24602253\x2db3f0\x2d4e3f\x2da5
        76ms minissdpd.service
        74ms alsa-restore.service
        72ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
        71ms packagekit.service
        65ms pppd-dns.service
        61ms user@1000.service
        59ms systemd-udevd.service
        52ms colord.service
        22ms polkit.service
        21ms gdm.service
        19ms networking.service
        17ms home.mount
        15ms systemd-sysusers.service
        14ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
        14ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
        13ms systemd-update-utmp.service
        13ms systemd-journal-flush.service
        13ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-38746a21\x2d574c\x2d4d6a\x2db751\x2d63f9db0
        12ms systemd-modules-load.service
        11ms systemd-user-sessions.service
        11ms systemd-remount-fs.service
        10ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
        10ms kmod-static-nodes.service
         9ms dev-mqueue.mount
         8ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
         7ms console-setup.service
         6ms systemd-sysctl.service
         6ms systemd-random-seed.service
         5ms dev-hugepages.mount
         5ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         4ms systemd-rfkill.service
         4ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
         4ms ifupdown-pre.service
```

Comment: You might have uninstalled the software, the hw is still there. It does not make a difference, if you want to disable the logs blacklist the offending kernel module.

Comment: Sure, so there is a way.

But how to save Bluetooth and repair it?